# Using the Facebook JS SDK in a Module (webpack)

Tags: javascript, facebook, webpack

I'm using webpack to keep my JavaScript code organized in modules but I'm running into a problem trying to load the Facebook JS SDK. I've tried using the `externals` option of webpack but since the library is loaded asynchronously I don't think it will provide the answer I am looking for.

There was an issue for webpack that addressed this problem. However, I don't think it works any longer. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/367

What would be a good approach to this problem? Should I just load the SDK synchronously?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a good solution. Just reference `window.FB` for now.

Answer (score 1):

As webpack is just a module bundler you should use a module loader to do the job, as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) if you want to use AMD modules or simply use this lib [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js) that you can do like that.

```
import $script from "scriptjs";

$script("//url/thescript.js", () => {
  // ...
});
```

EDIT:
Wrapping in something more simple to use:

```
import $script from "scriptjs";

export default function importAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $script(url, resolve); //just a simple, version. You should treat the reject case
  });
});
```

And then simply use it like:

```
//...
importAsync("//url.to/script.js").then(module => {
  //...
})
```

This way will be much more simple if you want to change your module loader in the future :)

Comment: I know this question is getting old but I wonder if you can use `import().then()` now and avoid using a tool like `scriptjs` altogether.

Comment: Or more likely something like `fetch()`

Comment: As I've said, unfortunately webpack is just a module bundler, and don't know how to treat asynchronous remote modules. For this, if you want something more organized, you can use requireJS and make you webpack export your final bundle to AMD.
Is not a good practice at all to use fetch to get the script (text), and after try to do a eval() by hand, let the module loaders to this for you :)

Comment: You can simply wrap this into a function
https://gist.github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/0c4f871e810fc5f8a3b723befc059348